# Refreshing the same component without redirecting

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got a search component where I redirect to a search results page. The search component is located in the `nav-bar` and it is rendered in every page including the search results page. Now I'm using `react-router` to redirect to the results page and my code looks as following. (I'm posting only the render function)

```
<FormGroup className={this.props.className}>
    <FormControl key='search' id='search' type='text' placeholder='Search Packages' value={this.state.searchKey} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.handleOnSearchValChange} />
    <i className='glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback' /> {this.state.searchResults.length > 0 &&
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/search', searchResults: this.state.searchResults, }}/> }
</FormGroup>
```

This works well in every page but, when I try to search when I'm in the same path as the `redirect` component, I get an error in my console as following.

```
You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/search"
```

I get the point that there is not point of redirecting while on the same path so my question is, how can I write this code in a more professional manner?

Comment: Can you create codepen please? It's hard to understand what is your component hierarchy

Comment: Provide the search query as URL params, so that it is a different route. You're trying to redirect to the same route, and hence the error. Giving different URL params will necessarily re-render the component. Will be happy to show you if you can provide more relevant code

Comment: @TheReason unfortunately I cannot create a codepen

Comment: @Dane changing URL params kind of break the entire app logic.

Comment: Then can you update a question with with your component hierarchy?

Comment: then use `this.props.history.push()` instead of redirect, and pass any data through `location` prop